# Check whether a record is updated in postgres database from java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

How can I know from java whether a record is updated when update query is called.
I had tried the return type int from executeUpdate() but it will show 1 whenever the query is executed. That is if the record is changed or not it will return value > 1.
If there is an opportunity for trigger in postgresql for calling a java method()
would be helpful for this. 
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by *updated*? When some column value has been changed?

Comment: I want to know which column is affected by the update

Comment: @AntonyJoslin Why? What's the end result you're looking for? What will you do with the information that some column(s) were updated?

Comment: Its for popping up a window to show another user that a column which both working have been updated.

Comment: Its like popping up window of facebook when some one shares or likes our post.

Comment: @AntonyJoslin Well, now you're going into complicated territory. There's no concept of "working on the same column" unless you create it yourself. Copying from the world of CVS this would involve some sort of "checking out" of data, so that changes to it can be tracked, turning this into a very broad question all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

`executeUpdate(Query)` will return number of rows updated

```
int rows = statement.executeUpdate("Your_query");
System.out.println("number of rows updated "+rows);
```

rows will be `0` if nothing updated

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know whether a row's data was *changed* as a result of the update, you would need to pass the parameters to the `WHERE` clause, making a statement such as `UPDATE foo SET bar = $1, baz = $2 WHERE bar <> $1 AND baz <> $2 AND id = $3`. Example is assuming you wish to update two columns of a single row based on `id`.

After that the only way the `WHERE` clause will match is if there is an actual update to do, and you can use the return value to check if an update occurred or not.

Another possibility is to refactor your code so that you don't need to bother about it, but you will need to explain your use case further for that.