# How to get DB column updated notification in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql

Is there any way to know whether a Database column is updated in Postgresql when calling update function in Java in Eclipse? I tried using trigger, but it will only give the number of rows updated. I need to know which column is updated.

Comment: Are you by any chance working with the author of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734853/check-whether-a-record-is-updated-in-postgres-database-from-java-jdbc/38735272) question, or is it just an amazing, unbelievable coincidence?

Comment: Yes, We are working together. And sorry for the inconvenience. I haven't noticed him posted the same.

Comment: Well, like I explained in that comment, there is no ready made mechanism to let you know which column was updated. Plenty of workarounds though, such as first loading the row before performing the update, then comparing.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your prompt reply Mr.Kayaman